# woocommerce cart session duplicating

Tags: session, woocommerce, cart

I have a client who is experiencing issues with their Wordpress/WooCommerce website.

Issue: The website is automatically adding products to the cart (Roughly 40-60). The issue occurs for both logged-in & logged-out users. The issue can occur when trying to login to the My Account section, when adding items to the cart or sometimes after adding items to the cart and then visiting the cart it will override cart items with new random items.

I have noticed that in WC_Session_handler the value for _customer_id is often not unique nor is the other session data.. I have removed all server & front-end caching, searched for any other sessions initialized.

Any help would be appreciated as they are losing business due to customers not being able to remove the items from their cart (As the removed items re-appear quickly)..

Domain Name: thecoffeehopper.com :)

Comment: Dunno how we are supposed to help you here … whoever implemented this auto-add-to-cart functionality needs to do some proper debugging.

Comment: The add to cart button doesn't need using for the issue to happen. The DB table woocommerce_session will automatically acquire a new entry with the serialised cart items in upon visiting the my_account in some instances.. wondering if anyone had a similar issue..?

Answer (score 1):

The cart is constructed from data in the wp_woocommerce_sessions and wp_usermeta MySQL tables.

I would run the following sql queries to try and find the source of your problem.

```
select * from wp_woocommerce_sessions;

select * from wp_usermeta where meta_key like '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_%';
```

The data from these rows are used to construct the cart. Are the random items found in any of these rows? The rows have a user id or customer id to tell which customer the data belongs to.

The data in these rows are serialized strings and is difficult to read directly so I would use the WordPress CLI tool and apply the function maybe_unserialize() to the SQL results.